# Add more items to verify Ajax/PHP

Tags: php, ajax

i find this script to verify (coupon) simple validate ,in PHP only a single word i"pizzapie"

but i dont know, how to add more (etc 15x) words like "pizzapie" to php, and validate it?

`function check_value_in_database($s) {
    return ($s== "pizzapie");`

Answer (score 0):

change your function like this

```
    function check_value_in_database($s) {
        if($s== "pizzapie" || $s== "something" || $s== "something2"){
        return true;
        }else { return false; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Have a great day!